# Mac verify error: invalid password? when trying to convert .pfx to .pem

Tags: openssl, pkcs#12

I have installed `openssl` on a Microsoft Windows machine and I was trying to do this conversion:

From:

- `.pfx`

To:

- `.crt`
- `.pem`
- `.key`

But I keep getting this error trying to use certificate:

```
Mac verify error: invalid password?
```

Comment: What command/s or code have you used to try to convert it?

Comment: Note that this question is useful also for whatever operating system with support to openssl.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the "mac verify error: invalid password" error too. But after I put the password in the command line like this, it works for me:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out myoutput.pem -nocerts -nodes -password pass:<mypassword>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was special characters in password which confuse argument parser. So call without `-password ...` argument and typing password on request did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this error with a password stored in a text file.
Even though the password in the file looked fine using cat or vi or nano, apparently openssl is sensitive to whitespace characters and line terminators as I believe in our case the password file given us by the cert authority was created in Windows. Running dos2unix on the file allowed the -password file: parameter option of the openssl command to then work successfully in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

For xelat's solution, it's no longer working if you create `.pfx` with OpenSSL 3 because AES-256-CBC is a new default cipher despite most of devices are not supporting it. To solve this, use this command instead:

```sh
openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out myoutput.pem -nocerts -nodes -password pass:<mypassword> -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -nomac
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that as already said you should have a password that come with a pfx/p12/... file **but** in case they have **not** shared with you any password, maybe the password is just an empty one. In this case, try with `-passin pass:` to express an empty password.

Example:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in input.p12 -out output.pem -nocerts -nodes -passin pass:
```

If this does not work either, I strongly suggest that you contact the owner of the file and ask them in good faith for the password that was used so that you can perform the conversion.