# Mac verify error: invalid password? Converting .p12 to .pem using openssl pkcs12

Tags: openssl, pkcs#12

I keep getting this error:

```
Mac verify error: invalid password?
```

For these two commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushKey.pem -in moo.p12

openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushKey.pem -in moo.p12 -nodes
```

moo.p12 is issued by apple for push notifications

Comment: I found that using weak password worked (lowercase letters), however using a strong password (uppercase letters, numbers and punctuation) did not (this is **not a solution**).

Comment: Maybe duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229386/mac-verify-error-invalid-password-when-trying-to-convert-pfx-to-pem

Answer (score 25):

You should have a password that come with the pfx file.

Try to put the password in the command line like this. Then you'll get both the private key and certificate in pem format:

```
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushKey.pem -in moo.p12 -nodes -password pass:<mypassword>
```

Comment: When using the CLI in windows I had to prepend the command with winpty and having the password specified as above allowed me to proceed while trying to enter the prompt when not specifying the -password resulted in the Mac verify error

Answer (score 4):

Note: as already said, you should have a password that come with the pfx file.

In case they have **not** shared with you any password, maybe the password is just an empty one. In this case, try with `-passin pass:` to express an empty password.

Example:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in input.p12 -out output.pem -nodes -passin pass:
```

And if you remembered that there is a password, good for you! Use that:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in input.p12 -out output.pem -nodes -passin pass:"YOUR PASSWORD"
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71584593/3451846

---

Note: if there is a password but you can't remember it, contact the author of that file and get the password.

If you really cannot remember the password, you have a problem. That problem cannot be solved by you, or by StackOverflow. Unless you have a bruteforce power using a quantum computer or something alien like that.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelEr, I clarified in the answer how to specify a password as you suggested